# React/HTML/CSS button text not centering on mobile; works fine on all desktop browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, button

I'm totally perplexed by this - the app is a simple React project, but the button is simple HTML with CSS styling. The text inside the button element - which should be centered - works fine on all desktop browsers, but everything is right-aligned on iPhone. The button includes a FontAwesome icon and some text, which are on different lines, but when I remove either it doesn't make a difference, the problem persists. I don't have the ability to inspect the code on my phone, and all desktop iPhone emulators online don't show the problem. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

JavaScript/JSX (state contains FontAwesome icon and text):

```
<div className='textcontainer'>
     <button disabled={this.state.disabled} 
           onClick={e => this.handleOpen(this.props.id)} 
           className='opencapsule' 
           id={this.props.title + '_button'}>
           {this.state.clock}
           <span className='opentext'> {this.state.status}</span>
      </button>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.textcontainer {
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
}

.opencapsule {
    margin:0 auto;
    color: white;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    line-height: .8rem;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

.opentext {
    font-size: .8rem;
    line-height: 1rem;
}
```

Live version of current app: https://timecapsule.now.sh/capsules

Comment: See my answer below. Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it:

On your button element, `.opencapsule`, add `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;`, like so:

```
.opencapsule {
    margin:0 auto;
    color: white;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    line-height: .8rem;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    display: flex;  //add this
    justify-content: center;  //add this
}
```

I'm not completely sure why the icons are not being centered on mobile, it has something to do with the behavior of the `<svg>`. I tried many other ways of centering it on iphone, such as, `text-align: center;`, and `margin: auto;` and others, but the only way that worked for me on mobile was to center the icon by making the button `display: flex` and `justify-content: center`.

Comment: This was it, thanks! For some reason it didn't occur to me to use flex WITHIN the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the webkit center to .opencapsule

```
text-align: -webkit-center;
```